# The elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

The elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$, as I understand, are all the number from 1 to 20 included that are relatively prime to 20? I am having troubles finding a coherent definition of this kind of groups... I thought it should be: $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}=${$1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19$}  but it is written somewhere that $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}=${$\pm 1,\pm 3,\pm 7,\pm 9$}, which is somehow rational because the cardinality is the same, also because for every $g$, $-g$ might stand for the inverse of $g$ , it is in that case $20-g$, which would explain replacing $11$ with $-9$, but how come? This is a multiplication group and the addition is not relevant. I am confused and would appreciate you direct explanation...

Comment: I believe you are correct with $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}=${$1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19$}. Where did you read about $\Bbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}=${$\pm 1,\pm 3,\pm 7,\pm 9$}?

Comment: Here: http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/guide/section/35soln.pdf 
Question number 2...

Comment: Huh, I have never seen that notation before. In that case, both definitions should work, just use the one that makes more sense to you. I personally like the first version without negative numbers, but I can see how the symmetry of the second version could be appealing.

Comment: Right, $-9 \equiv 11 \pmod{20}$ etc., so the two are just different ways to write the same set, since the numbers don't stand for plain integers but for residue classes modulo $20$. It would be more correct to distinguish between integers and residue classes in the notation, but less convenient.

Comment: Still, $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$ is closed under multiplication and clearly includes $-1$, so $-n = (-1)n$ makes sense for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$.

Comment: One can use any complete system of reps for the cosets. The balanced (signed) reps are often more convenient for computation since they have smaller magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is not false, the notation $\pm a$ is rather used, when convenient, for $\mathbf Z_p$, $p$ a prime number.

In the specific case, you must understand that $ \mathbf Z /20 \mathbf Z$ is a`quotient ring` of $\mathbf Z$, and as such, there is defined an `addition` and a `multiplication` of its elements.  $(\mathbf Z /20 \mathbf Z)^\times$ denotes the units of this ring, i.e. the elements which have a multiplicative inverse. An element such as the residue class of $11$ actually is the set of integers $11+20\mathbf Z$, which differ from  $11$  by a multiple of $20$, so  $11+20\mathbf Z$ is indeed the same set as  $-9+20\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Balanced (signed) reps can be used for *any* modulus (not only primes). They work well for units too because units are closed under negation ("reflection").

Comment: I know, but I think there's a drawback in the case of a nonprime modulus: it can drive neophytes to think,  for instance, that $x^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$, as in a field.

Answer (score 0):

Many times it is a great advantage working with negatives. Suppose a train starts 
at 9 pm and takes 23 hours to reach its destination. To find the time of arrival what does one do? add 9+23 and take reminder wrt 24? We take short cut and caluclate  9-1= 8pm Because 23 is -1 mod 24. To prove the famous quadratic reciprocity law, Gauss used negatives while working modulo a prime.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem lies in the fact that the subtle distinction between

1. the set of cosets $\{x+20\mathbb{Z}:x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ with multiplication defined by $$(x + 20\mathbb{Z})\circ(y + 20\mathbb{Z}) = x y + 20\mathbb{Z}$$
2. the set $\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ and multiplication defined by $$x \circ y =(x \cdot y) \% 20$$ where $\cdot$ is the multiplication of $x, y$ "as integers" and $\%$ is the modulus operator

is so often mixed up (well, of course, they are essentially the same).

If you use the first definition, for example $17 + 20 \mathbb{Z}$ simply *is* the same set of integers (coset) as $-3 + 20 \mathbb{Z}$. Because two cosets $x + 20\mathbb{Z}$, $y+20\mathbb{Z}$ are equal if for its representatives $x, y$ the following holds:
$$ x \equiv y \pmod{20}\, .$$
You can write $\overline{-3}$ or $\overline{17}$ for the corresponding cosets of $20\mathbb{Z}$, then $\overline{-3} = \overline{17}$ and
$$\{\overline{1},\overline{3},\overline{7},\overline{9},\overline{11},\overline{13},\overline{17},\overline{19}\} = \{\overline{\pm 1}, \overline{\pm 3}, \overline{\pm 5}, \overline{\pm 9} \}$$ Not writing the overlines is a bit sloppy, because the elements aren't integers, they are cosets.

The second definition is inflexible. Strictly speaking $-3$ is not an element of this group. The right way (which borders on the pedantic) would be to define the multiplication for the set $\{\pm 1, \pm 3, \pm 5, \pm 9\}$ *again* and then show that this group is isomorphic to the group of the second definition.

Comment: But the non-coset notation can be flexible if one permits use of *any* rep. Just as for fractions where we choose one of $\,1/2 = 2/4 = \ldots $ for convenience, we can choose one of $\,-1\equiv 19\equiv \ldots\!\pmod{20}\ $